# What happens if operation with multiple transactions fail?

Tags: transactions, transfer

I was wondering what happens if we batch several transactions in one call (purge), is there any form of transaction scope? Does all transactions roll back if one fails? Eg. if funds run out from the sender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will all be 'backtracked', except for reveals. You can find this in apply.ml:

- [definition of `mark_backtracked` on line 704](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/366f64f3df266cf02a06412d6760f73626d0a2bf/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/apply.ml#L704)
- [important part on line 729](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/366f64f3df266cf02a06412d6760f73626d0a2bf/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/apply.ml#L729)
- [usage on failures on line 738](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/366f64f3df266cf02a06412d6760f73626d0a2bf/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/apply.ml#L738)

Comment: Thanks for this direct link to the code. Great to hear it has transaction scope and all will be "backtracked". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Any result will be recorded in the blockchain.